# Amazon's AWS.NodeHttpClient - no documentation :(

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm writing a lambda function where I have to write logs to Amazon's ElasticSearch Service. Backend is `Node.js`. I came across this example on github:

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples/blob/master/src/s3_lambda_es.js

Which uses `AWS.NodeHttpClient` on line 91. The official docs say nothing about it:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS.html

Nor is anything provided about `AWS.HttpClient` (looks like a sister class of `AWS.NodeHttpClient`)

So, has anyone used/modified this code successfully before? I really don't want to dig into the `node_modules` folder hunting for the class description

Answer (score 1):

The sample code works.

`AWS.NodeHttpClient` is a private API. So it's undocumented.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/8904e9c730fb2fccf9d201f66266a6e2cbb75348/lib/http/node.js#L10

Comment: Add some description here.